# why Java dependency injection in addition to Spring dependency injection in web applicaton

Tags: java, spring

I have seen a Spring application, and it uses spring dependency injection in addition to that some places I find Java Dependency injection. I am not sure why Java DI is used. I googled it, however, I can’t find an exact answer.
Anybody can explain why Java DI is used in addition to Spring DI?

Comment: What do you think _Java DI_ is?

Comment: I meant, "import javax.inject.Inject"

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection in Java is a way to achieve Inversion of control (IoC) in our application by moving objects binding from compile time to runtime. We can achieve IoC through Factory Pattern, Template Method Design Pattern, Strategy Pattern and Service Locator pattern too.

Spring Dependency Injection, Google Guice and Java EE CDI frameworks facilitate the process of dependency injection through use of Java Reflection API and java annotations. All we need is to annotate the field, constructor or setter method and configure them in configuration xml files or classes.

[This link may help you more](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/java-dependency-injection-design-pattern-example-tutorial)

To be simple, If you need Dependency Injection through Java you need to implement using some Design Patterns, which is time consuming. Frameworks like Spring helps to implement DI using annotations and configurations which are developed using specific design patterns. As a developer we need not worry about DI, we can just concentrate on our business logic.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16662443)

Comment: Yeah it's true, thanks for the review. Next time I'll take care about the links. It's good to know that my post served the purpose.